# Combining multiple emails in Outlook (without attachments)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, attachments

I am trying to archive a project communication and somehow accidentally created a single email with all the dates and communication in a single thread (inside a single new email)

I have no idea how I did this and can't recreate it in Outlook. Does anyone know how I would do this? It is similar to the steps shown [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Forward-multiple-messages-as-a-combined-single-message-2DE65840-C2C9-4024-B8F1-FB32D1EF2A1B), however each individual email appears as text in the body of the message, not as an attachment. This would be convenient for storage and printing as it allows me to archive as PDF instead of .ost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find an answer [here](https://blogs.stthomas.edu/lawtechnologycenter/2013/07/26/combine-multiple-outlook-messages-into-one-when-reply-or-forward-a-message/). This will work for now but I'm still wondering how I did this with a single drag and drop operation. I was attempting to move the files to a new folder on my side bar menu and it just popped a new window!

> The easy way is when you are in the new message screen, choose Insert and then Outlook Item. Now find the message(s) in the folder and choose Insert as text.